# How many Character in 1 MB .txt file?

Tags: android, string, android-intent

I'm developing an Android app, and it use Intent String, from an information that I've been read Intent putExtra can only tranfer String with max size 1 MB, I wondering how much String that I can put in it, because I want to put JSON and consider the length.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Well, single character takes exactly 8 bits to be stored in, that's `1 byte (B)`. So `1 MB = 1024KB` and `1 KB = 1024B` so `1 MB has 1024 x 1024 = 1,048,576 bytes`, that's `1,048,576 characters`, that includes everything